# IN Query not working for Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I would like to check retrieve items that have an attribute value that is present in the list of value I provide. Below is the query I have for searching. Unfortunately the response return an empty list of items. I don't understand why this is the case and would like to know the correct query.

```
  def search(self, src_words, translations):
    entries = []
    query_src_words = [word.decode("utf-8") for word in src_words]

    params = {
      "TableName": self.table,
      "FilterExpression": "src_word IN (:src_words) AND src_language = :src_language AND target_language = :target_language",
      "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":src_words": {"SS": query_src_words},
        ":src_language": {"S": config["source_language"]},
        ":target_language": {"S": config["target_language"]}
      }
    }
    page_iterator = self.paginator.paginate(**params)
    for page in page_iterator:
      for entry in page["Items"]:
         entries.append(entry)
    return entries
```

Below is the table that I would like to query from. For example if my list of `query_src_word` have: `[soccer ball, dog]` then only row with `entry_id=2` should be returned

[image]

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because in the query_src_word you have "soccer_ball" (with an underscore), while in the database you have "soccer ball" (without an underscore).

Change "soccer_ball" to "soccer ball" in your **query_src_words** and it should work find

Comment: Sorry, I added the underscore by mistake